# Get the Tags detail of AWS IAM user

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

I want to get the tags information of AWS IAM users using rest service or AWS Java SDK. I am not able to find any AWS SDK example or class to get the IAM user tag information.
Below is the example how I am getting list of users but I want to pull their tags detail also[image]

AmazonIdentityManagement iam= AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(awCreds).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
ListiamUsers=iam.listUsers().getUsers();

Can someone tell me how to do that?

I tried below program also to list the tags of a user but I am getting below error:
**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.**

public class ListUserTags {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String kSecret = "adfdskjfdjssfjdjfdsdumykeysecret3eiiid";
    String dateStamp = getConvertedDateString("yyyyMMdd", new Date());
    System.out.println("dateStamp:" + dateStamp);
    String regionName = "us-east-1";
    String serviceName = "iam";

    String xmzDate = getConvertedDateString("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'", new Date());;
    System.out.println("date:" + xmzDate);

    String signature = getSignatureKey(kSecret, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName); //signature


    System.out.println("signature:" + signature);


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().clone();
    //MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListUserTags&Version=2010-05-08&UserName=SVC_ServiceAccount04")
        .method("GET", null)
        .addHeader("host", "iam.amazonaws.com")
        .addHeader("X-Amz-Date", xmzDate)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ABC787dsfsdDummyAccessKey/" + dateStamp + "/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=" + signature)


    System.out.println("req:" + request.headers().toString());
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

}

static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
    return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}



static String getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
    byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    return Hex.encodeHexString(kSigning);

}

public static String getConvertedDateString(String format, Date date) {

    return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching the tags for a user can be done as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Please consider using aws configure and avoid hard-coding credentials
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_key_id");

    AmazonIdentityManagement iam = AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .build();

    // Create a request with the username for which we want to query the tags
    ListUserTagsRequest request = new ListUserTagsRequest().withUserName("username");

    ListUserTagsResult result;
    List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        result = iam.listUserTags(request);
        tags.addAll(result.getTags());
        request.setMarker(result.getMarker());
    } while (result.isTruncated());

    // Do something with the tags
    System.out.println(tags);
}
```

I think the code this self-explanatory. More in-depth documentation for AWS IAM Java sdk can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-iam-users.html).

Comment: Hi Ervin, Cant find iam.listUserTags(request); method in AmazonIdentityManagement class also can not find "ListUserTagsResult" class

Comment: You should probably use the latest version of amazon Java SDK: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk. I've tried it with 1.12.77 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [ListUserTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListUserTags.html). Seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: I tried the same but I am getting below error: <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>

Comment: I presume you are trying to hit it via http request, right? In this case you have to ensure that you are properly sending credentials in you request. Why don't you use the listUserTags present in the AWS Java SDK? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagement.html#listGroups-com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.ListGroupsRequest-